# Can I use JSON as a database?

Tags: php, sql, json

Currently, I am working on a website and just started studying backend. I wonder why nobody uses JSON as a database. Also, I don't quite get the utility of php and SQL. Since I could easily get data from JSON file and use it, why do I need php and SQL?

Comment: You definitely could - though databases give you some useful features, like concurrency, the ability to manage large datasets, schemas, and the ability to recover from crashes.

Comment: what is the database features you require (indexing, sorting, filtering, syncing, user permission, table/row locking, stored procedure, concurrent access, etc.)? also, why do you prefer using JSON? there are a lot of ways to get and set data to a text file, JSON, a DB engine, it really depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok! let assume you put the data in a JSON variable and store it in a file for all your projects.

- obviously, u need to add a subsystem for getting back up, then you will write it.
- you must increase the performance for handling a very large amount of data, just like indexing, hash algorithms, and... , assume u handle it.
- if you need some API for working and connecting with a variety of programming languages, u need to write them.
- what about functionalities? what if you need to add some triggers, store procedures, views, full-text search and etc? ok, you will pay your time and add them.
- ok, good job, but your system will grow up and you need to scale it, can you do it? u will write abilities for clustering across servers, sharding, and ...
- now you need to guarantee that your system will compatible with ACID rules, to keep atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, and Durability.
- can you always handle all querying techniques (Map/Reduce) and respond with a fast and standard structure?
- now it's time to offer very quick write speeds, it brings serious issues for you
- ok, now proper your solutions for condition racing, isolation level, locking, relations and ...

after you do all this work plus **thousands of many** others, probably you will have a DBMS a little bit just like MongoDB or other relational and non-relational databases!

so it's better to use them, however, obviously, you can choose to don't to use them too, I admit that sometimes saving data in a single file has better performance, but only sometimes, in some cases, with some data, for some purpose! if you know what exactly you do, then ist OK to save data in a JSON file.